# 4k Monitor fullscreen video playback in a pip window

Tags: windows, macos, video-streaming, fullscreen

I’m blessed with having a 43” 4k monitor at work, and as well, at home. I have both a MacBook Pro Retina and windows desktop computer hooked up to them. I love working on the monitors but I have one problem with it, watching videos. E.g. YouTube, Lynda.com, Netflix, etc. Within the video player there is a fullscreen button, that when pressed, it will make the video go fullscreen (like it should). But my problem is, I’m trying to multitask while having the video play. I was hoping there’s a way where I can press the fullscreen button and it will give me a resizable borderless window that is movable and able to keep-on-top option. I tried to do some research but came up short. So, I’m turning to you guys. How can one do something like this?

Thanks for reading and responding to my question,
Throdne

Answer (score 0):

The fullscreen mode in youtube actually takes over the entire screen so it doesn't mean you get a resizable pop up window. AFAIK youtube doesn't do resizable popup windows, but I'm sure you could make that happen with a little javascript.

If not, what you can do is open a separate browser window for your video, resize that to the size you want, and use the browsers zoom feature, for example set zoom to 200% and the video will be twice as large.

You may also be interested in an alternate UI that youtube offers which most people don't know about, it's designed for smart tv-s but you can access it from the pc too simply by going to [youtube.com/tv](http://youtube.com/tv) instead of the usual youtube.com
.

Answer (score 0):

That feature is announced for macOS 10.12.

You can use VLC for that.

Open Video in separate window.

`->` VLC `->` Settings `->` Interface `->` Uncheck Show Video in Main Window

Show video without window borders.

`->` VLC `->` Settings `->` Video `->` Uncheck Show Window Decorations

Then make the video always on top.

`->` Video `->` Always in Foreground

Open the Stream:

`->` File `->` Open Network `->` Paste Youtube URL